# setting text to bold using java

Tags: java, user-interface, jtextfield

I am creating a GUI with some JCheckButtons (bold italic), these buttons will turn the text in the text field to bold, italic or both when selected through the use of action listeners. Here is how I implement this functionality in my action listener methods (this is for the bold method, I also have similar methods for italic and bold and italic).

```
class Bold implements ActionListener {

    private final FontSetter fontSetter;
    private final JTextField textfield;

    Bold(FontSetter fontSetter, JTextField textfield) {
        this.fontSetter = fontSetter;
        this.textfield = textfield;
    }

    Font font = new Font(textfield.getText(), Font.BOLD,12);

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        fontSetter.setBold();
        textfield.setFont(font);
    }

}
```

error:
the blank final field textfield may not have been initialised,how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the `textfield` variable first before you use it. Since you have defined `font` as another instance variable, the reference to `textfield` may not have been initialized yet.

One possible approach is to initialize `font` on construction since it is dependent on `textfield`:

```
private final JTextField fontSetter;
private final JTextField textfield;
private final Font font;

Bold(JTextField fontSetter, JTextField textfield) {
    this.fontSetter = fontSetter;
    this.textfield = textfield;
    this.font = new Font(textfield.getText(), Font.BOLD, 12);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you have an instance variable, `textfield`, which you are initializing in the body of the class's constructor. You also have another instance variable, `font`, which you're initializing in the instance variable declaration. When you initialize `font`, you are accessing `textfield`.

If you read the [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), it describes the order of initialization. Unfortunately for you, the bulk of the constructor body is run after the instance variables are initialized. That means that when the `font` variable is initialized, the `textfield` variable hasn't been, yet.

As suggested by David Yee, the obvious change is to initialize the `font` variable in the constructor after you initialize the `textfield` variable, which gives a very clear and unambiguous ordering:

```
Bold(JTextField fontSetter, JTextField textfield) {
    this.fontSetter = fontSetter;
    this.textfield = textfield;
    this.font = new Font(textfield.getText(), Font.BOLD, 12);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**JTextField** is a plain text component that only allows write a single line, even if you can display text in any font you can't set it **bold**. To implements a formatted text area in your program, you should use a JTextPane or a **JEditorPane**. Follow this link for more information https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html

Comment: You certainly can set a JTextField to use a bold font.